# How to debug/display request sent using RestClient

Tags: ruby, http, debugging, rest-client

I am trying to use RestClient to access a webservice using post method. I am sending the authorization token as specified but I am still getting a 403 status error which means I am forbidden to use that api. Is there any way that I can see the request being sent with http post so that I can verify the headers? I am not able to find any example or any documentation which mentions as to how to do that?

My code is similar to this :

```
token = get_token

response = RestClient.post "https://api-dev.xxx.com/software/services/search/ABC",
  :authorization => "Bearer #{token}"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could try enabling `RestClient`'s logging and see whether this provides any useful output:

```
RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout path/to/my/program
```

or if you are using Rails

```
RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout bundle exec passenger
```

replacing `passenger` with your choice of server. This will redirect all logging to standard output (your console).

Personally I prefer using more verbose tools when I need to inspect or troubleshoot HTTP requests.

You could try `curl` or `wget` if you prefer command-line, or one of the many browser extensions which let you perform requests easily, inspect output, save for future use, set up different environments etc. Both [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) and [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) are good choices.

Comment: Just because it was confusing for me at first, if you're using heroku, this is also the way to do it. Just use `heroku config:set RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout`

Comment: What is path/to/my/program here? 

If I use the path to my project the command fails saying: "is a directory..." Any help is appreciated

Comment: @halbano: This is a shell syntax defining an environment variable only in the given command. Here `path/to/my/program` should be the shell command to use to run your application.

Answer (score 71):

If you're doing more of a REPL kind of development, it can be as easy as adding

```
RestClient.log = 'stdout'
```

to your code.

You can find [other valid values in the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.8.0/RestClient#log%3D-class_method).

Comment: I don't see the body of the POST request.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't know (or want to bother) to pass in env. variable to your app (in my case it was Passenger/Rails), do something similar:

```
$ cat >/usr/share/foreman/config/initializers/00_rest_client.rb <<'EOT'
require 'rest_client'
RestClient.log =
  Object.new.tap do |proxy|
    def proxy.<<(message)
      Rails.logger.info message
    end
  end
EOT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you craft a request manually, you can use [inspect](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb#L64) to show the full url

```
req = RestClient::Request.new(
    :method => :post,
    :url => "https://api-dev.xxx.com/software/services/search/ABC",
    headers: {params:{:authorization => "Bearer #{token}"}})

puts req.inspect
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the request from the exception:

```
def bla(token)
  response = RestClient.post "https://api-dev.xxx.com/software/services/search/ABC", :authorization => "Bearer #{token}"
rescue RestClient::Exception => e
   @logger.error "#{e.response.request.inspect}"
end
```