# How do I convert this curl command to Ruby rest-client put request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest-client

I have this `curl` command which I need to covert to **PUT** request

```
curl https://example.com/api/v2/students/id.json \
  -d '{"student":{"description":{"body":"Adding a new test description"}}}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -v -u test@gmail.com:Abcd1234 \
  -X PUT
```

#### Trial

I tried this **PUT**, but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any error, but it does not add the description.

```
put(
     "https://example.com/api/v2/students/id.json",
     {:student => {:description  => {:body => 'Adding a new test description.'}}},
     { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{authorization_token}" }
     )
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Snippets are for frontend JS/HTML/CSS problems. Other code should just be indented by four spaces (select the text and press the `{}` button on the edit window).

Comment: “Doesn’t work” means exactly what? Does it print an error message?

Comment: It does not throw any error message but is not adding the description that is given. It adds the description with the curl command

Comment: Try `{student: {description:  {body: 'Adding a new test description.'}}}`

Comment: Tried but not working. No error but not adding the description either

Comment: Are if.json and tickets a typo?  There is an error, but you are not capturing it

Comment: yeah it was a typo. i updated it. it is not in my request.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://example.com/api/v2/students/id.json \
  -d '{"student":{"description":{"body":"Adding a new test description"}}}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -v -u test@gmail.com:Abcd1234 \
  -X PUT
```

use

```
put(
     "https://test%40gmail.com:Abcd1234@example.com/api/v2/students/id.json",
     {student: {description: {body: 'Adding a new test description.'}}},
     #{'student': {'description': {'body': 'Adding a new test description.'}}},
     #{:student => {:description  => {:body => 'Adding a new test description.'}}}.to_json,
     {content_type: :json, accept: :json}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your curl example, you provided the body as a (JSON-formatted) string:

```
curl ... \
  -d '{"student":{"description":{"body":"Adding a new test description"}}}' \
  ...
```

The direct equivalent in rest-client would also use a (JSON-formatted) string:

```
put( ...,
  '{"student":{"description":{"body":"Adding a new test description"}}}',
  ...
)
```

According to the [README](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#readme):

> rest-client does not speak JSON natively, so serialize your payload to a string before passing it to rest-client.

---

You can use the rest-client log to show the actual HTTP request sent, and compare it with what curl sends.

- [How to debug/display request sent using RestClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463465/how-to-debug-display-request-sent-using-restclient)
- [How to display request headers with command line curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252851/how-to-display-request-headers-with-command-line-curl)

Comment: What was the difference in the HTTP request (as reported by the rest-client log and the curl trace)?